# Parameterized JUnit5 Test with all Classes with the same Baseclass

Tags: junit5, parameterized-tests

I try to run some tests on all classes that extends the same baseclass like:

```
   classe Baseclass {
abstract int method();
}

class A extends Baseclass { int method(){...} }

class B extends Baseclass {int method() {..}}

class Testclass {
    @ParameterizedTest 
    @ValueSource( classes={T extends Baseclass})
    void test(Baseclass T){
      assertStuff(T..)}}
```

The Testclass should execute the test method with class A and B.
When I add a Class C that extends BaseClass class C should automatically be tested to.
Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that [`@Tag`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering) can help you . Just tag the `Baseclass` with a tag such as :

```java
@Tag("baseClassTest")
classe Baseclass {
  abstract int method();
}
```

Then depending on how you run the test , you can specify you only want to run the tests with the tag `baseClassTest` meaning that to run all tests the extends `Baseclass`. So if a new test class that extends `BaseClass` is added , it also will be covered.

- For IntelliJ IDEA , you can refer to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html).
- For Maven , you can refer to [this](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-filter-tags).
- For Gradle , you can refer to [this](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle)